# ImageBrush for Grid programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

So I try to apply an image but cannot see any changes...

What do I am missing? Thanks!!

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.UriSource = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Images/bg1.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
bi.EndInit();
ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
ib.TileMode = TileMode.Tile;
ib.ImageSource = bi;
ib.Stretch = Stretch.None;
RootGrid.Background = ib;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var ib = new ImageBrush {
  ImageSource =
    new BitmapImage(
      new Uri(@"Images\bg1.jpg", UriKind.Relative)
    )
};

RootGrid.Background = ib;
```

Also, this is obvious, but make sure the image is actually at the right path and set to be Content in the Project.

Comment: Sorry I have an embedded image and your code gives me an error.

Comment: What is the error? And what is an embedded image? Do you have it set as `<Content>` in the project or as a `<Resource>` ?

Comment: I have as a <Resource> and it is DLL UserControl project.

Comment: ok I have fixed it   ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/MyDllName;Component/Images/bg1.jpg")));

Comment: Ah, ok. That pack uri syntax is hard to debug sometimes.

Comment: The solution proposed by @AcademyofProgrammer worked perfectly!